# How to set windows mobile image?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to set an image in this control how to do this?

```
<Image x:Name="ghngfhn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="-8,-47,0,-2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Comment: In Xaml or Codebehind? "Source" is the attribute you are looking for

Comment: In XAML and Properties window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml:

```
<Image Source="Images/EnterName.png" x:Name="ghngfhn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="-8,-47,0,-2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```